# CSS to format SSN form input

Tags: html, css, input, field

I have a form, written in HTML5 and CSS3, that has some very specific fields (SSN, Phone Number, Initial) that are varying lengths.  I am trying to figure out how to format the input field so it is only X characters long depending on the input (11 for SSN, 1 for Initial, 5 for ZIP... etc)

I know you used to be able to put size="11" and the input field (not the label) would be set to that size, however this seems to be disabled or is being overwritten with BS3.

Any suggestions on how to get this accomplished?

What I have for code at the moment is:

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="SSN">SSN:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="SSN" placeholder="###-##-####" size="12">
                </div>
```

But that does not seem to work, and if I try class="col-sm-2" (or any other number for that matter) the format gets all goofy (does not line up properly in some cases).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged `html5` you can use:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="SSN">SSN:</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="SSN" placeholder="###-##-####" maxlength="12">
</div>
```

By the way, `class="col-sm-2"` is a bootstrap class that defines the number of columns an element should span.  Visit http://getbootstrap.com for more info.

Be sure your html doctype is: `<!doctype html>` which more or less means 'use html5'.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Just tried that, and still pushed the input field the remaining length of the column. I am starting to think the bootstrap overwrites the size if input fields however I cannot find anything that says it does.

Comment: After playing around with that it appears that the max number of characters that can be entered is 12 (definately a desired result) however the actual input box is still the length of the column. I am looking at making that box smaller to reflect the actual size of the input max length.

Comment: No problem.  In bootstrap, the `form-control` class makes input fields 100% width.  It may be worth it for you to take some time to read bootstrap's documentation.  Also, if you are using Chrome, you can right click on the input and click `inspect element` to open Chrome Developer Tools.  There, you can see all CSS styles associated with an element (and also edit them live).